# replace() a GET string

Tags: javascript, replace

I am pretty new to JavaScript and i have never used the replace function before.
I have this string, that i would like to replace:

```
?character=
```

So far i have written:

```
replace(/\/?character=\/[0-9]?/, '/?character='+ $_GET["character"])
```

But i am pretty sure it is not the right way. I have already written a script, that makes it possible to use $_GET in my Javascript.

What i want is to replace **/?character=B** with **/?character=$_GET["character"]**

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = '/?character=B';
var b = a.replace(/(\/\?character=)B/, '$1'+$_GET["character"]);
console.log(b);
```

If the string to replace is always "/?character=B", this would work.